# Lipschitz necesary for solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x'=f(x)$. Is it possible that this equation has a solution in the interval $I$ if $f$ is not locally Lipschitz in $I$?

Comment: Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem

Answer (score 0):

As Siminore said, the Lipschitz condition is not necessary for existence: [Peano existence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem) requires only continuity.

The Lipschitz condition is not necessary for uniqueness, either. The [Osgood existence theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/55289) provides uniqueness and existence of solution under the hypothesis that is strictly weaker than the Lipschitz condition.